# how to fix explosive minigun blowing away enemies in V.A.T.S

Tags: pc, fallout-4

I am playing Fallout 4 vanilla survival level 50+ and I found a legendary Explosive Minigun.  I like using frag grenades so I maxed my Demolition perk before.  Now when I use the minigun in Vats, the enemy gets fragged and launched into the air, sometimes very far away.  Is there a fix for this?  I have had to swim into the middle of the sea one time due to it sending a legendary molerat flying out there.  Or is it because the minigun is too powerful? What if I maxed my Heavy weapons perk too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try to avoid using it in VATS on a small target.**

VATS will fire off a salvo of many bullets.  The explosive force in a volley of shots will cause smaller bodies to go flying.

It's like setting off 20 grenades in the area.

Comment: so there is no way to fix it.  Okay might as well just use my exploding automatic pipe pistol.  I will have to use the Minigun indoors only then.

Comment: @fja3omega Or as Nelson said, avoid using VATS. If you control fire, small bursts, they should not usually fly as far.

Comment: @Longspeak Yeps that too.  But I like VATS because the attack can be set to multiple opponents one after the other.  In one move all of them are dead.  Really helpful when fighting charred feral ghouls in popping their legs off.

Comment: With an explosive minigun, you don't need to target more than one guy.  The whole room is usually dead with one attack.

Comment: @Nelson I now have a policy of using the Minigun with VATS only in areas where the enemies can't fly off.  In open areas I go with my Explosive Automatic Pipe Rifle.  Explosive weapons are overpowered.